# Error "External table is not in the expected format" while importing excel data into db in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

I am getting an error

> External table is not in the expected format

while importing excel data into db in mvc.

### Table from Entity Framework

```
namespace MyCRS
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    
    public partial class tblStoreRequest
    {
        public int TransactionId { get; set; }
        public string DocumentNo { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime RequestedDate { get; set; }
        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        public int ArticleId { get; set; }
        public int RequestedQty { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        public string EnteredBy { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime EnteredOn { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    
        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser1 { get; set; }
        public virtual tblArticle tblArticle { get; set; }
        public virtual tblStore tblStore { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Request.xlsx

(data format in text as in am getting into `List<string>`)

```
## DocumentNo   RequestedDate   StoreId ArticleId   RequestedQty Remarks ##
##  REQ-5       02-09-2016      4       4           100 ##
```

### Controller Code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyCRS.Models;
using LinqToExcel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MyCRS.Contollers
{
    public class StoreRequestBulkController : Controller
    {
        MyCRSEntities db = new MyCRSEntities();
            
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
            
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult UploadExcel(tblStoreRequest storerequests, HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
        {
            List<string> data = new List<string>();

            if (FileUpload != null)
            {
                if (FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                    || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
                {
                    string filename = FileUpload.FileName;
                    string targetpath = Server.MapPath("~/Doc/");
                    FileUpload.SaveAs(targetpath + filename);
                    string pathToExcelFile = targetpath + filename;
                    var connectionString = "";

                    if (filename.EndsWith(".xls"))
                    {
                        connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", pathToExcelFile);
                    }
                    else if (filename.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                    {
                        connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 14.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", pathToExcelFile);
                    }

                    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString);
                    var ds = new DataSet();

                    adapter.Fill(ds, "ExcelTable");

                    DataTable dtable = ds.Tables["ExcelTable"];

                    string sheetName = "Sheet1";
                    var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathToExcelFile);
                    var artistAlbums = from a in 
                                       excelFile.Worksheet<tblStoreRequest>(sheetName) select a;

                    foreach (var a in artistAlbums)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (a.DocumentNo != null && a.RequestedDate != null)
                            {
                                tblStoreRequest TU = new tblStoreRequest();
                                TU.DocumentNo = a.DocumentNo;
                                TU.RequestedDate = a.RequestedDate;
                                TU.StoreId = a.StoreId;
                                TU.ArticleId = a.ArticleId;
                                TU.RequestedQty = a.RequestedQty;
                                TU.Remarks = a.Remarks;
                                TU.EnteredBy = Session["U"].ToString();
                                TU.EnteredOn = DateTime.Now;
                                db.tblStoreRequests.Add(TU);

                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                data.Add("<ul>");
                                if (a.DocumentNo == "" || a.DocumentNo == null) data.Add("<li> DocumentNo is required</li>");
                                if (a.RequestedDate.ToString() == "" || a.RequestedDate == null) data.Add("<li> RequestedDate is required</li>");
                                if (a.RequestedQty.ToString() == "") data.Add("<li> RequestedQty is required</li>");

                                data.Add("</ul>");
                                data.ToArray();
                                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                        {
                            foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                            {
                                foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                                {
                                    Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //deleting excel file from folder  
                    if ((System.IO.File.Exists(pathToExcelFile)))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(pathToExcelFile);
                    }
                    return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    //alert message for invalid file format  
                    data.Add("<ul>");
                    data.Add("<li>Only Excel file format is allowed</li>");
                    data.Add("</ul>");
                    data.ToArray();
                    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                data.Add("<ul>");
                if (FileUpload == null) data.Add("<li>Please choose Excel file</li>");
                data.Add("</ul>");
                data.ToArray();
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h4>Add Users via Excel</h4>
<hr />
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadExcel", "StoreRequestBulk", FormMethod.Post, 
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return myFunction()" }))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-md-2">Download Format:</div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <a href="/StoreRequestBulk/DownloadExcel/"><img 
src="~/excel.ico" width="25" height="25" title="Download Excel format" 
alt="excel" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-md-2">Excel:</div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" 
class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="btnSubmit" 
class="btn     btn-primary" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```